# ¿Cómo pasar datos de php desde archivo .js (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Tengo este problema, en mi pagina formulario.php tengo una variable de sesión llamada $_SESSION['user']. La venia trabajando sin problema:

```
<html>
... 
<script>
   let usuario = '<?php echo $_SESSION['user'] ?>'
</script>
... 
</html>
```

Esto funcionaba sin problema, pero estaba intentando sacar el código de javascript a un archivo .js para separarlo de mi html. Es aquí donde me genera error, puesto que en el archivo .js solo me lee código de javascript, y por esta razón no puedo llamar la variable de sesión que tengo en php. Alguien sabe si hay alguna manera de pasar el dato de una variable de php a Javascript, o llamar esta variable desde el archivo .js. Una alternativa es alojar la variable de php en un input(hidden), pero esto hace que el dato de mi variable sea visible al momento de inspeccionar la página desde el navegador, estoy tratando de evitar esta alternativa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el localStorage como alternativa, así:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 //con setItem creas el el registro local
  localStorage.setItem("usuario", "<?php echo $_SESSION['user'] ?>");
</script>
```

Y desde el archivo js puedes acceder al mismo localStorage para recuperar el valor que guardaste, así:

```
let usuario = localStorage.getItem("usuario");
```

Aún así, es posible ver el localStorage desde la consola del navegador en Aplicacion -> localStorage, por lo tanto si el valor es muy delicado será mejor que lo encriptes antes de guardarlo en el localStorage, puedes usa alguna librería sencilla como https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js para encriptar y desencriptar.

Comment: Excelente amigo, era justo lo que necesitaba.

Comment: pero ojo que el encriptado también lo pueden desencriptar con programas terceros... así que no es del todo seguro...